# How to Loop through a Table Tree with only MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, loops, select, tree

Things to know:

- I am inserting this statement inside of our Reporting software, so I
  don't have the luxury of using PHP to do the looping for me.
- I am not familiar with the LOOP clause inside MySQL, I did a little research before, but could use some help with the syntax.

Question:

**How would I loop through this MySQL statement? (Statement given below)**

The following statement works right now, I have further `CASE WHEN`'s to add it, but for now I'm trying to solve for the most confusing part of the whole thing.

I need to loop through the MySQL statement ( or find another way to write the same thing) until I reach the bottom of the tree. To illustrate what I am trying to do:

**Let's assume I need to get the Downline of this entire tree starting from the top. Which means I have to run this MySQL statement for each person below.**

[image]

In our current set-up, I store the `ID` of the person above them in the record like so, and to follow the record DOWN, I have to give it the Upline ID and return all the records where it has that Upline ID, which returns all the IMMMEDIATE downlines.

```
+---------+-------------+------+
| ID      | Upline ID   | Name |
+---------+-------------+------+
| 745753  | 654-64645-3 | John |
| 098678  | 916-59172-1 | Jill |
| 543272  | 866-99573-8 | Fred |
| 634543  | 126-97939-3 | Dean |
| 923461  | 734-84628-5 | Bill |
| 861345  | 643-01957-0 | Cris |
+---------+-------------+------+
```

This means for each row returned in the set, I have to follow the MySQL statement down each record tree individually, and do the same for each row returned, causing the MySQL statements to multiply, UNTIL, when I run the statement for that record, nothing is returned, so I reached the end of the downline.

Without further waiting, here is statement (I give it the first person at the top's `ID` in the `WHERE` clause to get the statement started):

```
    SELECT wn_writing_number_cstm.title_c, 
    wn_writing_number.`name`, 
    preps_contracted_reps.first_name, 
    preps_contracted_reps.last_name, 
    cac_customize_agent_comp_cstm.commission_percentage_c, 
    wn_writing_number_cstm.id_c
FROM wn_writing_number 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN wn_writing_number_cac_customize_agent_comp_1_c ON wn_writing_number_cac_customize_agent_comp_1_c.wn_writing946b_number_ida = wn_writing_number.id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN cac_customize_agent_comp ON wn_writing_number_cac_customize_agent_comp_1_c.wn_writing3148nt_comp_idb = cac_customize_agent_comp.id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN cac_customize_agent_comp_cstm ON cac_customize_agent_comp.id = cac_customize_agent_comp_cstm.id_c
     LEFT OUTER JOIN aos_products_cac_customize_agent_comp_1_c ON cac_customize_agent_comp_cstm.id_c = aos_products_cac_customize_agent_comp_1_c.aos_produca2b8nt_comp_idb
     LEFT OUTER JOIN preps_contracted_reps_wn_writing_number_1_c ON preps_contracted_reps_wn_writing_number_1_c.preps_contracted_reps_wn_writing_number_1wn_writing_number_idb = wn_writing_number.id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN preps_contracted_reps ON preps_contracted_reps_wn_writing_number_1_c.preps_cont9effed_reps_ida = preps_contracted_reps.id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN wn_writing_number_cstm ON wn_writing_number_cstm.id_c = wn_writing_number.id
WHERE wn_writing_number_cstm.wn_writing_number_id_c = '53506bbe-008f-577c-2114-576b32e0ad11'
```

**Here is a Query Builder Diagram to help illustrate this model:**

[image]

And finally, here is what this statement actually returns, I'd need to run this statement twice again, one for each row with the `ID` of each of those records in my `WHERE` clause:

```
+---------+-------------+------------+-------------------------------------+
| title_c | name        | first_name | last_name | percent_c | id_c        |
+---------+-------------+------------+-------------------------------------+
| A       | MP-AB0682-16| Andrea     | Donald    | 10        | 823462345   |
| GA      | RO-RM4619-16| Ronald     | Yeller    | 12        | 632811634   |
+---------+-------------+------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
```

Please comment for any further clarification needed. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you want 2 or 3 actual resultsets coming back and that your programming interface can process them, as such?

Comment: If you "cache" previous results and their level/iteration to a "temp" table, you can use that temp table to query for each level rather than every individual parent.

Comment: I would certainly do ^ because a loop/iterate or a cursor gets ugly

Comment: Or make a stored proc, which is always a great home for a self-join on hierarchies

Comment: @Drew when I've need to do this, a loop was still needed, but no cursor; you just loop until no more records are added and then do the final/results selection from the "temp" table.

Comment: A loop is a loop. I was focusing on my first comment though. I has to do with the consumer of it.

Comment: The report I'm building is essentially a contact list, where I pull in everyone in their downline's contact information, so a single temp table I could do one select on would be perfect. As for the software, I'm pretty confident it can process the result sets, but I won't know for sure until I test it both in NaviCat, then in the software itself. But so far it has handled fairly complex statements up to this point.

@Uueerdo, I'm unfamiliar with how to do what you are suggesting, can you give me some starting help at least, or where I could find to learn how to do this?

Comment: @Drew, well, I finally got everything working in NaviCat (also tested in phpMyAdmin), and the I got the query over there and it's kicking it back with a syntax error near `DELIMITER`. Our Reporting engine uses a JDBC driver to connect to the DB, looks like this might be a needle in a haystack issue because I looked online and it looks like there is a load of different options to skim through.

Comment: Well a delimiter is often used just to create the stored proc. Some environments need it, some don't (allegedly phpmyadmin). It is a chunk demarcation thing. I've never used a delimiter statement beyond its use for the creation of sp's, fcns, events, triggers. Just for the create part (once and done) like in my last answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38512724)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A semi-pseudo code answer to clarify my method (sorry, don't have time for a more precise solution, and don't use the syntax frequently enough to remember it exactly without looking it up):

```
DECLARE lastInsertCount INT;
DECLARE lastLayer INT;
CREATE TABLE `temp`
(
   `layer` int,
   [fields you want and parent's identifier]
);

INSERT INTO `temp`(`layer`, fields you want...)
SELECT 0, fields you want...
FROM theTable
WHERE [is "root" result]
;
SET lastLayer := 0;

SET lastInsertCount := 1;
LayerLoop: WHILE lastInsertCount > 0

  INSERT INTO `temp`(`layer`, fields you want...)
  SELECT lastLayer + 1, fields you want...
  FROM theTable
  WHERE parent_id IN (SELECT id FROM `temp` WHERE layer = lastLayer)
  ;

  SET lastInsertCount := ROW_COUNT();
  SET lastLayer := lastLayer + 1;

END WHILE LayerLoop;

SELECT fields you want...
FROM `temp`
;

DROP TABLE `temp`;
```

---

Edit: If you allow "cycles" in the tree, which would make it not a tree (but I've had to worry about it in bad data), you can avoid those causing you to loop infinitely by adding

```
AND id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM `temp`)
```

to the where clause.

Comment: I will be marking this as the correct answer, but just one last thing I can't figure out, I'm getting errors in the SQL syntax around the `DO WHILE`, instead of `rows_affected`, I'm tried `mysql_affected_rows()`, I also tried `WHILE mysql_affected_rows() > 0`, then `END WHILE` at the end instead of the `DO` then `WHILE`, but none of that works? Am I missing something?

Comment: Like I said, it is pseudocode, so the exact syntax may vary; I'm actually surprised it worked with such little modification... I'll see if I can make it closer to precise syntax.

Comment: @JoshWhitlow Updated answer to use more actual syntax; and replaced use of session variables (the `@` variables) with declared local variables.

Comment: I apologize for my lack of knowledge, I assumed I could copy paste this, and modify the `INSERT INTO` and `SELECT`, but after doing a lot of research I was finding things like the fact that `DECLARE` has to be used inside `BEGIN` and `END` statements, Which means I need a procedure, but supposedly the Procedure has to be stored with `DELIMITER`, and then I have to invoke it with `CALL`. But I'm doing something wrong because none of that is working. [Here](http://imgur.com/a/pM6rc) is a link to what I have so far using the most recent syntax you suggested. Where am I wrong?

Comment: On a quick glance: [DECLARE is permitted only inside a BEGIN ... END compound statement and must be at its start, before any other statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare.html); and it also looks like you missed changing an `i` on line 43. Also, you don't need the `;` on that last `END` (line 46). _Sidenote: you may not want to use the table name `temp`, but something more unique. With a true TEMPORARY table you wouldn't need to worry about this, but those have limitations that prevent them from being viable for this purpose._

Comment: That worked! Thanks for working through this with me! This is been really helpful and has also helped expand my knowledge of MySQL. I also had to put 'id_c' and not 'id' in the sub-select on line 58.